# VS Code integrated terminal shows path twice

Tags: visual-studio-code

Snapshot of the problem described in Title

[image: Snapshot of the problem described in Title]

After the latest update of VS Code today, I noticed this strange behavior.
I have iTerm2 and zsh installed. iTerm2 is working fine. Only in integrated terminal of VS Code, this issue is there.

UPDATE : This issue has been opened on github.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28359

Comment: Better ask someone related to these products in GitHub or something. Try opening an issue at [vscode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode)

Comment: I've noticed the same issue. If you find a solution please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

This was a VSCode bug which should be fixed in VSCode 1.13.1

Here is the original bug tracking the issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26038